# How do I Build a Dropdown List Using a Filter on a ForeignKey within a Model as Choices

Tags: python, django

I am build a model with a dynamic list based on record options that are available (List below will be in a separate table)

I have tried several option and continue to get the following error:

"CategoryCodes.active_ID: (field.E004) 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple)."

```
ALL = '0000'
SYSTEM = '9000'
BUSINESS = '9002'
INDIVIDUAL = '9005'
PROJECT = '9006'

PREFIX_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (ALL, '- All -'),
    (SYSTEM, 'System'),
    (BUSINESS, 'Business'),
    (INDIVIDUAL, 'Individual'),
    (PROJECT, 'Project')
)
```

class TypeOptions(models.Model):

```
type_ID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

type_code = models.AutoField('Code', primary_key=True, editable=False)
type_code_name = models.CharField('Code name', max_length=200, default="")
type_code_default = models.BooleanField('Code default', default=False)
datastructure_prefix_name = models.CharField('Segment',
                                             max_length=4, choices=PREFIX_TYPE_CHOICES, default=ALL)

datastructure_name = models.CharField(
    'Table name', max_length=50, default="")

datastructure_element_name = models.CharField(
    'Table element', max_length=50, default="")

#
#  Date/Time records was created
createDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#
#  Date/Time records was updated
updateDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

#
#  Active options the owner list
active_ID = models.CharField('Active state',
                             max_length=3, choices=ACTIVE_TYPE_CHOICES, default=ACTIVE)

#
#  This defines the sorting order
class Meta:
    ordering = ('datastructure_prefix_name', 'type_code')
```

---

class CategoryCodes(models.Model):

```
SCCID = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

state_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
state_code_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
state_code_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#
#  Date/Time records was created
createDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#
#  Date/Time records was updated
updateDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def get_option_list():
    return get_user_model().objects.filter(datastructure_prefix_name='ALL', datastructure_name='ALL', datastructure_element_name='active_ID')

def get_default():
    return get_user_model().objects.filter(datastructure_prefix_name='ALL', datastructure_name='ALL', datastructure_element_name='active_ID', type_code_default=True)

#
#  Active options the owner list
active_ID = models.ForeignKey('system.TypeOptions', choices=models.SET(
    get_option_list), default=models.SET(get_default), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I expecting to get a list that came be dynamically loaded into the option active_ID Based on filter

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `choices` param in a `ForeignKey`, but the error you're having is because ...

The function:

```
def get_option_list():
    return get_user_model().objects.filter(datastructure_prefix_name='ALL', datastructure_name='ALL', datastructure_element_name='active_ID')
```

does not return a list or tuple but a QuerySet.

You might want to use [QuerySet.values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) in that function in order to build the right data.

Perhaps:

```
def get_option_list():
    users = get_user_model().objects.filter(datastructure_prefix_name='ALL', datastructure_name='ALL', datastructure_element_name='active_ID')
    return users.values_list('id', 'username')
```